# How to Calculate Year-End Cumulative Living Population in an Access Database?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I'm working with a Microsoft Access database containing a large dataset spanning many years. The data includes individual records with fields for names, birth dates, and death dates. The death date field might be null, indicating the person is still alive. My objective is to craft an SQL query within Access that calculates the cumulative number of people alive at the end of each year (as of December 31st).

The query needs to consider each individual born on or before December 31st of each year and who is either still alive (null death date) or died after that year's end. My main challenge is achieving this efficiently given the substantial data volume and broad time range.

I’m specifically looking for a solution that can be implemented in Access. However, if your suggestion involves using a different database system, please indicate this clearly, along with specifying which database your script is intended for.

Any insights or examples for structuring this query effectively would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

I am only able to count births per year and deaths per year, and I don't know how to add up the data over the years. Unless using Excel.

What I Expected:

I want to implement it directly in SQL without the need for other tools, such as Excel.

Here is the sample input data:

| ID | Sex | BirthDate | DatahDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | female | 1973/5/12 | 2009/2/22 |
| 1 | male | 1974/2/3 | 1997/3/6 |
| 6 | male | 1975/8/15 |  |
| 7 | male | 1975/12/31 | 2004/3/21 |
| 16 | male | 1976/7/2 | 2011/12/8 |
| 13 | male | 1977/11/19 | 1995/4/17 |
| 15 | female | 1979/1/31 | 2018/8/8 |
| 8 | female | 1979/7/19 | 2008/9/2 |
| 11 | male | 1980/1/14 |  |
| 20 | female | 1982/3/12 | 1991/3/25 |
| 12 | female | 1984/2/29 | 1998/8/13 |
| 5 | female | 1984/11/12 | 1992/3/28 |
| 17 | female | 1986/1/7 |  |
| 3 | male | 1987/4/28 |  |
| 4 | female | 1988/7/23 | 2013/3/23 |
| 19 | male | 1989/5/30 | 2004/7/25 |
| 18 | female | 1989/8/11 | 2012/6/23 |
| 10 | female | 1991/2/8 | 2008/4/12 |
| 14 | female | 1991/2/10 |  |
| 9 | female | 1994/3/1 | 2015/5/12 |

Here is a sample result, which I obtained through calculations using formulas in an Excel spreadsheet.

| YearEnd | population | male | female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1973/12/31 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1974/12/31 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1975/12/31 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 1976/12/31 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 1977/12/31 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 1978/12/31 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 1979/12/31 | 8 | 5 | 3 |
| 1980/12/31 | 9 | 6 | 3 |
| 1981/12/31 | 9 | 6 | 3 |
| 1982/12/31 | 10 | 6 | 4 |
| 1983/12/31 | 10 | 6 | 4 |
| 1984/12/31 | 12 | 6 | 6 |
| 1985/12/31 | 12 | 6 | 6 |
| 1986/12/31 | 13 | 6 | 7 |
| 1987/12/31 | 14 | 7 | 7 |
| 1988/12/31 | 15 | 7 | 8 |
| 1989/12/31 | 17 | 8 | 9 |
| 1990/12/31 | 17 | 8 | 9 |
| 1991/12/31 | 18 | 8 | 10 |
| 1992/12/31 | 17 | 8 | 9 |
| 1993/12/31 | 17 | 8 | 9 |
| 1994/12/31 | 18 | 8 | 10 |
| 1995/12/31 | 17 | 7 | 10 |
| 1996/12/31 | 17 | 7 | 10 |
| 1997/12/31 | 16 | 6 | 10 |
| 1998/12/31 | 15 | 6 | 9 |
| 1999/12/31 | 15 | 6 | 9 |
| 2000/12/31 | 15 | 6 | 9 |
| 2001/12/31 | 15 | 6 | 9 |
| 2002/12/31 | 15 | 6 | 9 |
| 2003/12/31 | 15 | 6 | 9 |
| 2004/12/31 | 13 | 4 | 9 |
| 2005/12/31 | 13 | 4 | 9 |
| 2006/12/31 | 13 | 4 | 9 |
| 2007/12/31 | 13 | 4 | 9 |
| 2008/12/31 | 11 | 4 | 7 |
| 2009/12/31 | 10 | 4 | 6 |
| 2010/12/31 | 10 | 4 | 6 |
| 2011/12/31 | 9 | 3 | 6 |
| 2012/12/31 | 8 | 3 | 5 |
| 2013/12/31 | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| 2014/12/31 | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| 2015/12/31 | 6 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you show some effort and tell us what you have tried.  Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Show sample data and desired output as formatted text tables. Attempted SQL would be nice as well. Could post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. To accomplish in Access might call for a combination of SQL aggregation and a report using aggregate calcs.

Comment: I have post the sample data and result. Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @June7's answer, I came up with another solution as below, also using 3 queries:

1. Enter the sample data into a table named "Stats".
2. Create a query endDates to collect EndDates of all events

```
SELECT DISTINCT endDates.enddate
FROM (SELECT DateSerial (Year([BirthDate]), 12, 31) AS EndDate FROM Stats
UNION select iIf (DeathDate is not null, DateSerial (Year([DeathDate]), 12, 31), null) AS enddate FROM Stats
) AS endDates
WHERE (((endDates.enddate) Is Not Null));
```

3. Create a Cartesian product of Stats and endDates, then add filters

```
SELECT Stats.ID, Stats.Sex, Stats.BirthDate, Stats.DeathDate, endDates.enddate
FROM Stats, endDates
WHERE (((Stats.BirthDate) <= endDates.enddate) And ((endDates.enddate) < Stats.DeathDate) or ((Stats.DeathDate) Is Null));
```

4. Get the result through the pivot table.

```
TRANSFORM Count (filter.[ID]) AS ID_Count
SELECT filter.[enddate], Count (filter.[ID]) AS ID_Subtotal
FROM filter
GROUP BY filter.[enddate]
ORDER BY filter.[enddate]
PIVOT filter.[Sex];
```

I'm not sure if it's more efficient (feel free to comment), but I think this solution is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This does get complicated. Requires a sequence of queries.

Query1:

```
SELECT ID, Sex, BirthDate AS EventDate, DateSerial(Year([BirthDate]),12,31) AS EndDate, "Birth" AS Category FROM Stats
UNION SELECT ID, Sex, DatahDate, DateSerial(Year(Nz([DatahDate],#12/31/3000#)),12,31), "Death" FROM Stats;
```

Query2

```
TRANSFORM Sum(IIf([Category]="Birth",1,-1)) AS SumYearPop
SELECT EndDate, Sum(IIf([Category]="Birth",1,-1)) AS Pop
FROM Query1
GROUP BY EndDate
PIVOT Sex;
```

Next step is to calculate running sum. It is simple to build a report that does a running calculation with textbox RunningSum property. What I have provided will show records only for those years that have data. Forcing records for years with no data would require either dummy data in table or join Query1 (or each SELECT line) or Query2 to a dataset that has all possible years.

I find that CROSSTAB will not work as source for a running total query. Query2 can be replaced with:

```
SELECT EndDate, Sum(IIf([Category]="Birth",1,-1)) AS SumYear, 
Sum(IIf([Sex]="female",IIf([Category]="Birth",1,-1),0)) AS SumYearFem, 
Sum(IIf([Sex]="male",IIf([Category]="Birth",1,-1),0)) AS SumYearMale
FROM Query1
GROUP BY EndDate;
```

This does work as source for a running sum query. Example:

```
SELECT Query2.EndDate, 
(SELECT Sum(SumYear) FROM Query2 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.EndDate<=Query2.EndDate) AS RunPop,
(SELECT Sum(SumYearFem) FROM Query2 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.EndDate<=Query2.EndDate) AS RunFemale,
(SELECT Sum(SumYearMale) FROM Query2 AS Dupe WHERE Dupe.EndDate<=Query2.EndDate) AS RunMale
FROM Query2;
```

Be aware that queries involving correlated subqueries can perform slowly with large datasets.

Comment: Great solution, by converting the date of birth and death into an increase or decrease in the number uniformly, and then the result can be calculated by simple date filtering and summation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mind I modify the second Query2 and the Query3(the last query)? As the sex column and SumYear shouldn't appear in the Query2, or else some EndDate will repeat, such as 3000/12/31.

Comment: Good point. When I modified from CROSSTAB to simple GROUP BY aggregate, I forgot to remove Sex field. I will edit answer.